# Custom webpack configuration for angular karma tests not resolving Components but works for Directives

Tags: angular, webpack, karma-jasmine, karma-webpack

I made custom webpack config for angular karma and when starting tests, getting this message for each test with @Component decorator:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'ɵcmp' of undefined
> at getComponentDef (http://localhost:9876/*karma_webpack*/main.js:71825:14)

[image]

Tests with @Directives working without errors.

I'm adding for angular build in custom webpack config following plugin and rule with disabled aot(jitMode=true):
[image]

**Package versions:**

- webpack 5.36.2
- @ngtools/webpack 11.2.11

has anyone faced such a problem?